# Error installing pycrypto in mac 10.9.6

Tags: python, pycrypto

I am trying to install 'fabric'. I tried using 'pip install fabric' and the installation is failing when it is trying to install the 'pycrypto'

I see it is fetching the 2.6.1 version. I tried installing lower versions and I am getting same error.

'sudo easy_install fabric' also throws same error.

I also have the gmplib installed. I have the lib file in these places
/usr/lib/libgmp.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgmp.dylib

`pip install fabric
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): fabric in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko>=1.10.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko-1.14.1-py2.7.egg (from fabric)
Downloading/unpacking pycrypto>=2.1,!=2.4 (from paramiko>=1.10.0->fabric)
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446kB): 446kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pycrypto/setup.py) egg_info for package pycrypto
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ecdsa in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ecdsa-0.11-py2.7.egg (from paramiko>=1.10.0->fabric)
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... yes
    checking for __gmpz_init in -lmpir... no
    checking whether mpz_powm is declared... yes
    checking whether mpz_powm_sec is declared... yes
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
    checking limits.h usability... yes
    checking limits.h presence... yes
    checking for limits.h... yes
    checking stddef.h usability... yes
    checking stddef.h presence... yes
    checking for stddef.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
    checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
    checking for string.h... (cached) yes
    checking wchar.h usability... yes
    checking wchar.h presence... yes
    checking for wchar.h... yes
    checking for inline... inline
    checking for int16_t... yes
    checking for int32_t... yes
    checking for int64_t... yes
    checking for int8_t... yes
    checking for size_t... yes
    checking for uint16_t... yes
    checking for uint32_t... yes
    checking for uint64_t... yes
    checking for uint8_t... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
    checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
    checking for memmove... yes
    checking for memset... yes
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating src/config.h
    building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/src/_fastmath.o
    src/_fastmath.c:83:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    size = p->ob_size;
                         ~ ~~~^~~~~~~
    src/_fastmath.c:86:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    size = -p->ob_size;
                         ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    src/_fastmath.c:113:49: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            int size = (mpz_sizeinbase (m, 2) + SHIFT - 1) / SHIFT;
                ~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
    src/_fastmath.c:1310:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'unsigned int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    offset = mpz_get_ui (mpz_offset);
                           ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/local/include/gmp.h:840:20: note: expanded from macro 'mpz_get_ui'
    #define mpz_get_ui __gmpz_get_ui
                       ^
    src/_fastmath.c:1360:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    return return_val;
                    ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~
    src/_fastmath.c:1373:27: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    rounds = mpz_get_ui (n) - 2;
                           ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
    src/_fastmath.c:1433:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            return return_val;
            ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~
    src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                            else if (result < 0)
                                     ~~~~~~ ^ ~
    src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                            else if (result < 0)
                                     ~~~~~~ ^ ~
    9 warnings generated.
    src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                            else if (result < 0)
                                     ~~~~~~ ^ ~
    src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                            else if (result < 0)
                                     ~~~~~~ ^ ~
    2 warnings generated.`

This is the error i get when i execute 'fab'

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fab", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in 
    working_set.require(requires)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pycrypto>=2.1,!=2.4`

Answer (score 0):

Got it working after installing xcode.

pycrypto was installed by default once xcode was installed and fabric is working now.

(I should have mentioned that I am new to MAC in the question)